# Google App Engine - How to deploy constantly running code?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Sorry for the poor title but I couldn't think how else to word it.

I've deployed an application to Google App Engine which uses servlets to service requests to my server's URI. The servlets are instantiated on-demand by the container but I haven't seen anything in the documentation about how to deploy code which just runs constantly in the background (i.e the equivalent of a main method which runs upon deployment for lack of a better explanation) which can be referenced by the servlets. I'd appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Note: unless you have set app engine to manual scaling or you are using managed vms you cannot have code that constantly runs in the background. If the former is true you don't scale, so you can replace your app like your would do without app engine (see Andrei's answer). If the latter is true you're on your own anyway. If you scale automatically though you can basically just switch to a new version on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Deploy your code as a new version.
2. Spin up new instances.
3. Change the default version to the new one.
4. Shut down old instances.

It is your responsibility to make sure that your code shuts down gracefully.

Note that new and old instances still share Memcache/datastore, which you can use to pass any data that is necessary for seamless transition.